# A constrained maximization problem for a general function $f:\left(a,b\right)^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and $f:\left(a,b\right)^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a (possibly non-linear) function. I want to maximize $f$ on the region :
$$S=\left\{\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right) \in \left(a,b\right)^n : x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_n\right\}$$

i.e., I want to find :

$$\max_{\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right) \in S}{f\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right)}$$

**Question :** What are some general methods to work with such maximization problems?

---

**What I know :** In my multivariable calculus course, I have learnt about unconstrained maxima problems (with the second derivative tests, i.e. taking *gradient* of $f$ to be $0$ and showing that the *hessian matrix* at the critical point to be negative definite and so on). Also, I have learnt about constrained maxima problems with lagrange multiplier method.

---

I think that one needs some other methods to solve such *irregular* ($S$ looks pretty irregular to me!) optimization problem which I have not learnt yet. If anyone knows any method to tackle this and can share that, it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Without further assumptions on $f$ you should not expect any general method to work. Just imagine $f$ being a constant function almost everywhere. You need some property such as concavity or Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: @LinAlg : What are some results with added conditions on f?

Comment: Concavity: first-order methods, (quasi)newton-based methods, ADMM. Lipschitz continuity: global optimization.